# Div doesn't stay visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 links. When I click the first link div 1 should be displayed and the other 3 hidden.
When I click link 2, div 2 should be displayed and the other 3 hidden, and so on...

What I did:

- With CSS I've set the class of the 4 divs to `display: none`
- Created 4 functions with javascript that set the display property of the correct div to `block` and the 3 others to `none`
- Call the function when clicking the link

When I click a link, the div is shown for a quarter of a second but then it disappears again

CSS:

```
.CatDiv {
    display:none;
}
```

JS function:

```
function showKadoballonnen() {
    document.getElementById("Kadoballonnen").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("Geschenkmanden").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("Pampercadeaus").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("OrigineleVerpakkingen").style.display = "none";
}
```

Calling the function:

```
<a href="" onclick="showKadoballonnen()">Kadoballonnen</a>
```

Div that has to be called:

```
<div id="Kadoballonnen" class="CatDiv">TEST</div>
```

```js
function showKadoballonnen(e) {
  e.preventdefault();
  document.getElementById("Kadoballonnen").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("Geschenkmanden").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Pampercadeaus").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("OrigineleVerpakkingen").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.CatDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showKadoballonnen(e)">Kadoballonnen</a>

<div id="Kadoballonnen" class="CatDiv">TEST</div>
<div id="Geschenkmanden" class="CatDiv">TEST</div>
<div id="Pampercadeaus" class="CatDiv">TEST</div>
<div id="OrigineleVerpakkingen" class="CatDiv">TEST</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide more of your HTML/CSS? Better if create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: http://users.telenet.be/seijuki/test/products.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style.display block/none problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594042/style-display-block-none-problems)

Comment: @divy3993 Or use a Stack OVerflow snippet, it's the document icon with the `<>` in it!

Comment: @somethinghere I am not OP. :-)

Comment: @divy3993 I know but I've made it my mission on SO to ween people off JSFiddle and into SO snippets. I just think they are a lot nicer. :)

Comment: Ok great will take it into consideration.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jquery for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is easier than you think. In your  tag you got "href" with empty parameter. It makes your page reloading while pressing on it.
So all you should do is to write "#" as a parameter.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showKadoballonnen()">Kadoballonnen</a>
```

Comment: Actually, thats not _really_ an issue. You should do `onclick="showKadoballonnen(); return false;"` to cancel out the click.

Comment: Yes found that out too :-) thnx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid empty `href` attribute on a link. Use a button instead.

If it still does not work, attach your method to `window` object. Also, I don't recommend this approach, you should handle it in your Javascript by targetting at your DOM elements using an ID for example and adding your event listener from here.

```
document.getElementById('myelement').addEventListener('click', showKadoBallonnen);
```

Comment: Maybe add a bit about `preventDefault()`, as you are clearly on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code, and you also need to stop your link (`<a>`) firing.

On your link, add `return false;`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showKadoballonnen(); return false;">Kadoballonnen</a>
    <!-- ^ Also, add href="#" so you don't have an empty href -->
```

Also, add semicolons to the end of each line of your javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Kadoballonnen").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("Geschenkmanden").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("Pampercadeaus").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("OrigineleVerpakkingen").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem while writing some coffeescript in a rails application. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1136088/2909897) helped me.

The solution is the `event.preventDefault()` as shown below:

app/views/posts/index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Some link", '#', id: 'some-link' %>

<div class="some-div">
  <h4>Some list</h4>
  <ul id='some-list'>
    <li>cats</li>
    <li>and</li>
    <li>dogs</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

app/assets/javascripts/posts.coffee:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#some-link').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#some-list').toggle()
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to make it working: https://jsfiddle.net/ke81koj6/

```
function showKadoBallonnen() {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("four").style.display = "none";
}
```

**EDIT**

Edited the fiddle and now works with the press on a button. It's better to use a button than an anchor with a empty `href`.

HTML:

```
<button id="button" onclick="showKadoBallonnen()">click here</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = showKadoBallonnen;
```

Comment: Stays the same with me... tried it the first time with them, and deleted them afterwards to check if that was the problem.

Comment: Thansk to automatic semicolon insertion this is not the issue. @Hugo seems close, but you probably just need to `return false;`